# How to organize slices in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was reading on how to use `createAsyncThunk` and I have seen that my slices are not well organized.

I have `offer`. Users can see all offers, they can also create one, see one, have offer categories, etc..

For me, one slice was "subject/category" like this:

```javascript
// Axios request to get all offers, post one, get categories offers, etc..

    const offerSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'offer',
      initialState: {
        allOffers: [],
        OtherOffers : [],
        oneOffers: {},
        categoriesOffers: []
      },
      reducers: {
        setAllOffers: (state, action) => {
          state.allOffers = action.payload;
        },
        setOneOffer: (state, action) => {
          state.oneOffers = action.payload;
        },
        setCategories: (state, action) => {
          state.categoriesOffers = action.payload;
        },
        otherOffers: (state, action) => {
          state.OtherOffers = action.payload;
        },
      },
    });
```

So know, i was reading some StackOverflow post, and I have seen that one slice is more like "one subject".

For example, here, it is better to just have one slice for oneOffer, one for allOffers, one for categories...

So, I am lost. What is the right way to use slice from redux-toolkit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally recommended to have separate slices for different parts of the state, especially if those different parts have different concerns, or if they are updated by different actions. Having separate slices for different parts of the state can help keep the code more organized and easier to understand. In this case, having one slice for `oneOffer`, another for `allOffers` and one for `categories` would make sense as they are different data structure and updated by different actions. This way, you can keep the state and the reducers that manipulate that state organized and easy to reason about.

```
// oneOffer slice
const oneOfferSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'oneOffer',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    setOneOffer: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

// allOffers slice
const allOffersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'allOffers',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    setAllOffers: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

// categories slice
const categoriesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'categories',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    setCategories: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

In this example, each slice has a unique name, an initial state, and one reducer function that can be used to update its state. The oneOffer slice has an initial state of {} and an action setOneOffer which updates the state with the payload. The allOffers slice has an initial state of [] and an action setAllOffers which updates the state with the payload. Finally, the categories slice has an initial state of [] and an action setCategories which updates the state with the payload.

You would then need to combine these slices using the `createAsyncThunk` function or some other way to pass the data from the api calls to the states.

Comment: Ok, that what I was thinking ! thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, there is no right way to use your slice here. Both method are ok.
It all depends on how *YOU* want to organize it, and how you will access it in your app. But more importantly, on writing an easy to maintain app.

I personaly seperate slices depending on the database.
For example, if I have a `user` and an `offer` table, I will create 2 slices.

For your example, I would combine my reducers like this :

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  offers: offers.reducer,
  categories: categories.reducer,
})
```

Then, I can create a `const offers = useSelector...` and a `const categories = useSelector...`

With this method, you can easily write maintainable and easy-to-read code.

As per [Redux](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) documentation,

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of the state.

Hope my advice helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same as you have done in one of my projects and that's working fine. So, please don't get confused with the implementation.
For reference,

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  userInfo: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    challengeName: '',
    code: '',
    firstName:"Guest"
  },
  userRoles: {},
  error: '',
};

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginLoading: (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload !== undefined) {
        state.loading = action.payload;
      } else {
        state.loading = true;
      }
    },
    loginError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    loginUserInfo: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
    },
    loginReset: (state) => {
      state.userInfo = initialState.userInfo;
      state.error = initialState.error;
    },
    SetUserRoles: (state, action) => {
      state.userRoles = action.payload;
    }
  },
});

const { actions, reducer } = loginSlice;
export const {
  loginLoading, loginError,
  loginUserInfo, loginReset, SetUserRoles
} = actions;
export default reducer;
```